# Sharepoint Excel attachments suddenly not opening?

Tags: excel, sharepoint

I've been working on a process that copies attachments to a couple places. Here's the basic outline:

1. User adds attachments to Power App
2. Power App adds those attachments to SharePoint list item
3. Power App/Automate adds those attachments to Freshdesk ticket
4. Power Automate copies attachments from SP to send confirmation email to user.
5. When FreshDesk ticket is closed, Power Automate reads attachments from Freshdesk notes and adds them to 1) an email to the original user and 2) the original SP list item.

Everything seemed to be working fine, but I am suddenly having issues specifically with Excel attachments. I can open them in their original OneDrive location, the emails they're attached to (although the Excel previewer doesn't always want to open), and in the FreshDesk ticket. I cannot open them in SharePoint. I just get an error that "This workbook cannot be opened."

These exact files were working fine before. I've cleared my cache, restarted by computer, and tried a different browser. Nothing will let me open them from my SP list. Help!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Solved, thanks to the folks on r/sharepoint! It's a Microsoft bug. You can view it in the M365 admin Center under Health. Description below.

SP411415 :

Title: Users can't open recently created Excel files from within SharePoint Online lists

User Impact: Users are encountering an error when attempting to open Excel workbooks from SharePoint Online lists.

More info: Affected users will see the following error:
"The workbook cannot be opened"

Current status: The fix has been submitted and we anticipate that deployment of the fix will start within the next one to three days. We're monitoring its progress to ensure the fix gets deployed and saturates throughout the affected environment.

Scope of impact: Any user hosted on the affected infrastructure will be impacted.

Root cause: A recent service update contains a code error within the previewing function which is causing an exception, resulting in impact.

Next update by: Thursday, August 11, 2022, 4:00 AM (9:00 AM UTC)